# Apply function (quantile) to matrix rows and use result to modify row

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix, A, filled with random values with shape 10x10. How can I perform a function on each row (finding the 75th quantile), and divide each element in that row of A by that result?

In the below attempt, I am getting a single value for q, but q should be at least 10 values (one for every row). At that point I should be able to do element-wise division with `A/q`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(10 * 10), 10, 10)
q <- c(quantile(A[1,], 0.75))
A/q
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's `rowQuantiles` from the `matrixStats` package:

```
library(matrixStats)
res <- A / rowQuantiles(A, probs=0.75)
```

Same result?

```
identical(apply(A, 1, quantile, probs=0.75), rowQuantiles(A, probs=0.75))
[1] TRUE
```

Is it faster?

```
library(microbenchmark)

    microbenchmark(apply=apply(A, 1, quantile, probs=0.75),
                   matStat=rowQuantiles(A, probs=0.75))
    Unit: microseconds
        expr     min       lq    mean   median      uq       max neval cld
       apply 788.298 808.9675 959.816 829.3515 855.154 13259.652   100   b
     matStat 246.611 267.2800 278.302 276.1180 284.386   362.075   100  a
```

On this matrix, definitely.

What about on a bigger matrix (1000 X 1000)?

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), 1000, 1000)

microbenchmark(apply=apply(A, 1, quantile, probs=0.75),
               matStat=rowQuantiles(A, probs=0.75))
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min       lq     mean    median       uq      max neval cld
   apply 115.57328 123.4831 183.1455 139.82021 308.3715 353.1725   100   b
 matStat  74.22657  89.2162 136.1508  95.41482 113.0969 745.1526   100  a
```

Not as dramatic, but still yes (ignoring the max value).

Answer (score 3):

Solved the issue by using `apply`, as below:

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(10 * 10), 10, 10)
q <- apply(A, 1, quantile, probs = c(0.75),  na.rm = TRUE)
A <- A/q
```

It technically answers the question, but a vectorized approach would be nice.

Comment: The final line is vectorized, so at least you have 1 out of 2.

Comment: Next time you ask and answer your own question, use the "Answer your own question" tickbox at the bottom of the ask page. That way you can post both question and answer at once and save others (me, G5W, who already deleted their answer) from working on and posting the same thing.

Comment: @Gregor Didn't know I would be answering it when I asked it.